# Filter folders whose name is a timestamp - pattern matching vs. regex matching using the find utility

Tags: regex, shell, glob, find-util

I am writing a generic shell script which filters out files based on given regex.

My shell script:

```
files=$(find $path -name $regex)
```

In one of the cases (to filter), I want to filter folders inside a directory, the name of the folders are in the below format:

```
20161128-20:34:33:432813246
YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS:NS
```

I am unable to arrive at the correct regex.

I am able to get the path of the files inside the folder using the regex `'*data.txt'`, as I know the name of the file inside it.

But it gives me the full path of the file, something like

```
/path/20161128-20:34:33:432813246/data.txt
```

What I want is simply:

```
/path/20161128-20:34:33:432813246
```

Please help me in identifying the correct regex for my requirement

**NOTE:**

I know how to process the data after

```
files=$(find $path -name $regex)
```

But since the script needs to be generic for many use cases, I only need the correct regex that needs to be passed.

Comment: it's not a regex it's a wildcard!

Comment: you mean, what I require is a wildcard and not a regex?

Comment: no, I just meant that you cannot use regexes with `find`. Only wildcard patterns (you use a wildcard)

Comment: Use -regex instead of -name to enable regular expressions.

Comment: @pkalinow That is, assuming your version of `find` supports `-regex`, which is not mandated by the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), `find`'s `-name` `-path` primaries (tests) use [***patterns***](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) (a.k.a wildcard expressions, globs) to match filenames and pathnames (while patterns and regular expressions are distantly related, their syntax and capabilities differ significantly; in short: patterns are syntactically simpler, but far less powerful).

  - `-name` and matches the pattern against the *basename* (mere filename) part of an input path only
  - `-path` matches the pattern against the whole *pathname* (the full path)
- Both GNU and BSD/macOS `find` implement **nonstandard extensions**:

  - `-iname` and `-ipath`, which work like their standard-compliant counterparts (based on *patterns*), except that they match *case-insensitively*.
  - `-regex` and `-iregex` tests for matching pathnames by ***regex* (regular expression)**.

    - Caveat: Both implementations offer at least 2 regex dialects to choose from (`-E` activates support for *extended* regular expressions in BSD `find`, and GNU `find` allows selecting from several dialects with`-regextype`, but no two dialects are exactly the same across the two implementations - see bottom for the gory details.

---

With your folder names following a fixed-width naming scheme, a *pattern* would work:

```
pattern='[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Of course, you can take a shortcut if you don't expect false positives:

```
pattern='[0-9]*-[0-9]?:[0-9]?:[0-9]?:[0-9]*'
```

Note how `*` and `?`, unlike in a regex, are not *duplication* symbols (quantifiers) that refer to the preceding expression, but *by themselves* represent any sequence of characters (`*`) or any single character (`?`).

If we put it all together:

```
files=$(find "$path" -type d -name "$pattern")
```

- It's important to *double-quote* the variable references to protect their values from unwanted shell expansions, notably to preserve any whitespace in the path and to prevent premature globbing *by the shell* of value `$pattern`.
- Note that I've added `-type d` to limit matching to *directories* (folders), which improves performance.

---

**Optional background information**:

Below is a **regex feature matrix** as of GNU `find` v4.6.0 / BSD `find` as found on macOS 10.12.1:

- GNU `find` features are listed by the types supported by the `-regextype` option, with `emacs` being the default.

  - Note that several `posix-*`-named regex types are misnomers in that they support features *beyond* what POSIX mandates.
- BSD `find` features are listed by `basic` (using NO regex option, which implies platform-flavored [BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)) and `extended` (using option `-E`, which implies platform-flavored [EREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)).

For cross-platform use, sticking with [POSIX EREs (*extended* regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) while using `-regextype posix-extended` with *GNU* `find` and using `-E` with *BSD* `find` is safe, but note that not all features you may expect will be supported, notably `\b`, `\<`/`\>` and character class shortcuts such as `\d`.

```
=================== GNU find ===================
== REGEX FEATURE: \{\}
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      -
TYPE: ed:                                         ✓
TYPE: emacs:                                      -
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    -
TYPE: grep:                                       ✓
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  -
TYPE: posix-basic:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                -
TYPE: posix-extended:                             -
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        ✓
TYPE: sed:                                        ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: {}
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         -
TYPE: emacs:                                      -
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       -
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  ✓
TYPE: posix-basic:                                -
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        -
TYPE: sed:                                        -
== REGEX FEATURE: \+
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      -
TYPE: ed:                                         ✓
TYPE: emacs:                                      -
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    -
TYPE: grep:                                       ✓
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  -
TYPE: posix-basic:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                -
TYPE: posix-extended:                             -
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        -
TYPE: sed:                                        ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: +
TYPE: awk:                                        ✓
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         -
TYPE: emacs:                                      ✓
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       -
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  ✓
TYPE: posix-basic:                                -
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        -
TYPE: sed:                                        -
== REGEX FEATURE: \b
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         ✓
TYPE: emacs:                                      ✓
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       ✓
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  -
TYPE: posix-basic:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        ✓
TYPE: sed:                                        ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: \< \>
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         ✓
TYPE: emacs:                                      ✓
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       ✓
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  -
TYPE: posix-basic:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        ✓
TYPE: sed:                                        ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: [:digit:]
TYPE: awk:                                        ✓
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         ✓
TYPE: emacs:                                      -
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       ✓
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  ✓
TYPE: posix-basic:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        ✓
TYPE: sed:                                        ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: \d
TYPE: awk:                                        -
TYPE: egrep:                                      -
TYPE: ed:                                         -
TYPE: emacs:                                      -
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    -
TYPE: grep:                                       -
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  -
TYPE: posix-basic:                                -
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                -
TYPE: posix-extended:                             -
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        -
TYPE: sed:                                        -
== REGEX FEATURE: \s
TYPE: awk:                                        ✓
TYPE: egrep:                                      ✓
TYPE: ed:                                         -
TYPE: emacs:                                      ✓
TYPE: gnu-awk:                                    ✓
TYPE: grep:                                       -
TYPE: posix-awk:                                  ✓
TYPE: posix-basic:                                -
TYPE: posix-egrep:                                ✓
TYPE: posix-extended:                             ✓
TYPE: posix-minimal-basic:                        -
TYPE: sed:                                        -
=================== BSD find ===================
== REGEX FEATURE: \{\}
TYPE: basic:                                      ✓
TYPE: extended:                                   -
== REGEX FEATURE: {}
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: \+
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   -
== REGEX FEATURE: +
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: \b
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   -
== REGEX FEATURE: \< \>
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   -
== REGEX FEATURE: [:digit:]
TYPE: basic:                                      ✓
TYPE: extended:                                   ✓
== REGEX FEATURE: \d
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   -
== REGEX FEATURE: \s
TYPE: basic:                                      -
TYPE: extended:                                   ✓
```

Comment: worked like a charm!!, it works even without `-type d`

Comment: @ADPK: Glad to hear it; yes, if the name pattern is specific enough, you don't strictly need `-type d`, but adding it will help performance, because `find` will then only look at directories.

Answer (score -1):

When you have a full path of a file, then you don't need a regex to extract the directory name.

```
dirname "/path/20161128-20:34:33:432813246/data.txt"
```

will give you

```
/path/20161128-20:34:33:432813246
```

If you really want a regex, try this:

```
\d{8}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{9}
```

Comment: I feel this cannot be the answer, as the question was more specific on arriving at the wildcard or correct -regex.

Comment: Given that the OP did not show any attempt at defining a regular expression in the question, it would not surprise me if this is exactly what they were looking for.

Comment: The OP is using `'*data.txt'` as an _incidental example_ of a pattern that happens to work, but the intent is clearly to match the directory names directly, and to have `find` output the directory paths directly (as opposed to having to apply `dirname` after the fact).
As for your regex: (a) Neither GNU nor BSD `find` support character-class shortcut `\d`, and (b) for use with `-regex`, the _entire path_ must be matched, not just the filename part.