# Shell script to backup filtered directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have several directories that I want to backup to a zip file with a shell script. Directory tree looks like this:

```
testing
     |_ source
     |     |_ fiction_01
     |     |_ fiction_02
     |     |_ ...
     |     |_ images
     |
     |_ destination
```

I only want to zip directories starting with the same pattern, say, `f*`. Not interested in `images`. The resulting zip should be saved to `destination`. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40868764/10152848), I get how to filter all directories whose name start with `f`. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# source and destination directories passed as 1st and 2nd parameters respectively
 SRCDIR=$1
 DESTDIR=$2

# children directories are those matching f*
 CHLDIR=$(find "$SRCDIR" -type d -name "f*") 

# name with timestamp for the .zip 
 BKPNAME=backup-$(date +%-Y%-m%-d)-$(date +%-T).zip

# actual zipping
 zip -r $DESTDIR$BKPNAME $SRCDIR$CHLDIR
```

The script is named `backup.sh` and lives in `destination`. This is what I get after running it:

```
jm@lenovo410:~/Documents/testing/destination$ bash backup.sh ../source/ ./
  adding: ../source/../source/fiction_02/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ../source/../source/fiction_02/another.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: ../source/fiction_01/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ../source/fiction_01/list.txt (stored 0%)
```

The zip file is created in `destination` directory. Even though it seems both `fiction_01` and `fiction_02` (and their content) were added, when I check inside the zip there is only directory `fiction_01`.

**Question**: How can I zip all folders whose name match the condition `f*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathnames returned by `find` already begin with `$SRCDIR`, you don't need to concatenate it when you run `zip`. You're trying to add `/testing/source/testing/source/fiction_01` to the zip file.

```
zip -r $DESTDIR$BKPNAME $CHLDIR
```

When you're debugging a shell script, one the best tools is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see a trace of all the commands that are executed, with variables expanded. Then you would have seen these incorrect pathnames.

Comment: And thank you for the `set -x` advice too! I'm new to this.